# Primary Key Id is not working while using .net core web Api CRUD with MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, crud, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm working on generating a primary key _id for Students class while using .net core web api CRUD operation on a MongoDB database and i tried literally everything and still not working
my documents class is:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace Entities
{
    public class Student
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] 
        public string id { get; set ;}

        public string name { get; set; }
        public int grade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but it's still giving me the opportunity to enter an id while testing my api in swagger, just like this:
[image]

Comment: Hey, welcome to the stack overflow community. Please don't paste screenshots and use plain text instead. Also provide a clear full repro of your issue(but simplified if possible) with a clear description, I didn't get the problem from your comment

Comment: Can you post your post method here?